# Could Teletype Model 33 ASR console work on a desktop, without the dedicated stand?

Tags: terminal, teletype

Definitely, the earlier teleprinters, like Model 15 and even earlier could be put on a table. But for some reason the fashion shifted and most hard-copy terminals in the 1960s and 1970s used a special stand.

Comment: [Possibly recognizable individual](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/how-bill-gates-school-launched-his-lifes-work/).

Comment: @HABO thanks https://assets3.cbsnewsstatic.com/hub/i/r/2013/05/10/14c07de9-1c4e-11e3-9918-005056850598/thumbnail/1200x630/600ecca5f162a415eeda056ed4783c53/OOGatesTour1280_1.jpg

Comment: @Anixx, can you clarify whether you are specifically interested in the ASR33, or (as I implicitly assumed) any Model 33 Teletype?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  At my university, the undergrad computing lab had rows of tables with ASR33 and KSR33 teletypes, with the latter probably being in the majority.

I dispute the 'most' part of the question. I'd say that was quasi-normal where there was a single tty, say as a console terminal, but not when you had them in quantity.

For the most part, I don't really distinguish between ASR33 and KSR33, though of course I know the difference. Looking at photos, it seems that if you're going to make much use of the punch on the ASR33, then you'll need to position it such that a chad box can hang below the table level.

---

The [Teletype Model 33 Technical Manual](http://bitsavers.org/communications/teletype/33/273B_Mod32_33_TechMan_Jan63.pdf) describes the stand as an optional accessory. I took a screen-shot of the relevant paragraph; below.
[image: Model 33 teletype manual]

Comment: I wonder, if there is any photo on the net?

Comment: I couldn't find any 'university lab' photos but [this photo of a 1900 console](http://www.briantownsley.com/assets/images/autogen/Scan-140111-0071.jpg) demonstrates why a desk was superior: 1960s and 1970s computing required something to support manuals, printouts, etc. (and the 'music stand' attachment on the teletype was inadequate).  The 1900 console is really a modified teletype, with a few lights and switches added, but the point stands.

Comment: I think, this ICL 1900 was shipped with a computer, so was not available for a separate purhase?

Comment: The ICL 1900 is a computer (or rather, a series of computers with model numbers 190x).  But yes, the console terminal came with the computer, being specifically modified for that purpose. Except for one low-end model, the 1900 didn't have 'lights and switches' for operator control. Nevertheless, the sitting on a desk part is entirely normal, and this was the only photo I could find.

Comment: That ICL 1900 installation looks like it is using the KSR-33 variant i.e. that wasn't an ASR-33 as it does not appear to have a papertape reader. Tried Google for any better photos and drew a blank. The photos that I did find with an ASR-33 all used the metal stand.

Comment: Right. The 1900 console was neither an ASR33 nor exactly a KSR33.  It was modified for ICL use ([see illustration near end of page](https://icl1900.co.uk/icl1900/cpus.html)). I only picked it as a convenient photo of 'model 33 on a desk'.

Comment: Still believe this is not the correct answer for the question asked.

The referenced Teletype manual is for three different models of Teletype with two (KSR and RO models) having the stand as an optional accessory. This is why the clause describing the stand has it listed as an option for the Model 33 series. This manual for the 33 (KSR) and 33 (RO) models is where the metal stand is an option.

Comment: For the 33 ASR, Section 2, 2-16 Power Pack Assembly, b. "The  Auxiliary ASR Power Supply is mounted in the enclosure of the stand".

2-17 Tape Punch, b. "Installation of Chad Box Assembly (Figure 2-13) , (2) "Push the box towards the rear until a bent surface located at the front of the box engages the printer stand".

For the ASR 33 model the stand was not optional.

Comment: Found the Teletype Corporations's Product Description for the Model 33 ASR which documents that stand was not optional. Updated my answer.

Comment: Believe this seemingly plausable but incorrect answer just received another upvote.

Answer (score 5):

The Teletype Model 33 ASR console **did not work** on a standard, flat desk. They were always sold with an integral metal stand. The metal stand on a Model 33 ASR was not optional. That is why they were commonly seen in computer installations with the metal stand. All online photographs of complete Model 33 ASR teletypes include the metal stand.

The reference is [Teletype Corporation, 1969 Price List and Product Descriptions M28, M32, M33, M35](https://bitsavers.org/communications/teletype/33/273B_Mod32_33_TechMan_Jan63.pdf):

```
Teletype Corporation
Product Descriptionn 50 (P.D. 50)
Change 11
Dated October 1, 1969
    
Teletype Corporation Model 33Cl Standard Duty Send-Receive Page
Printer Set with Tape Perforator and Reader with these features: 
        
Equipment Features and Components
        
Tape Reader Features
Power pack mounted in sheet metal stand
        
General Information
Set shipped completely assembled less stand and chad box
    
Dimensions
Stand: (Supports teletypewriter)
```

The stand was integral to the Model 33 ASR while it was optional for the RO and KSR variant.

The Bitsavers site currently has [Technical Bulletin 273B](https://bitsavers.org/communications/teletype/33/273B_Mod32_33_TechMan_Jan63.pdf) , a copy of the Teletype Corporation:

```
Technical Bulletin 273B
Technical Manual
Manual Model 32 and 33
Send-Receive Page Printer Sets (KSR)
Receive-Only Page Printer Sets (RO)
Automatic Send and Receive Sets (ASR)
```

Other relevant Teletype manuals covered spare parts, wiring diagrams, etc. Unfortunately I could not find online copies of these other volumes of the maintenance set.

In the Teletype Corporation manual being used as the reference some variants of a Model 33 teletype could easily be used on a desk without the metal stand. Catch is the Teletype Model 33 ASR is the exception due to the papertape reader and punch.

A page printer only mechanism i.e. the Model 33 RO model (Receive Only) could have easily been installed on a flat desktop or table as it didn't have the papertape reader or punch. The Keyboard Send-Receive (KSR) model did not have a papertape reader or punch so a desk could be a viable option.

It is very likely that people sitting at a teletype on a desk would not know the difference between a Model 33 KSR they were using and the Model 33 ASR model. They can all be seen as teletypes from Teletype Corporation.

The component list of a Model 33 ASR always included a papertape reader and punch, this defined the Model 33 ASR from the other variants.

The Teletype manual described the RO and KSR variants that could be easily installed on a flat table. Therefore the metal stand is described as an optional extra. The reference is:

```
Section 1 Description
1-9. STAND (Figure 1-2).
Available as an accessory is a sheet metal
stand which will support the equipment at 
a convenient operating level. ...
```

At this point an assumption could be made that the metal stand was optional for all variants. The text continues:

```
It consists of chrome feet and an enclosure
which will house auxilary apparatus such 
as a Data Set and reader power pack. A 
removable rear panel provides access to this
enclosure. ...
```

As the Teletype Model 33 ASR always included a papertape reader and punch it required the required the enclosure on the metal stand.

Clauses relevant to the Model 33 ASR are included in Section 2 Installation,

```
2-16 Power Pack Assembly, b.
The Auxiliary ASR Power Supply is 
mounted in the enclosure of the stand.

2-17 Tape Punch, b.
Installation of Chad Box Assembly (Figure 2-13),
(2) Push the box towards the rear until
a bent surface located at the front of 
the box engages the printer stand.
```

Additionally the manual includes:

```
Section 7 Principles of Operation
7-17 Tape Reader
The power pack is attached inside the
printer stand.
```

As the teletype use mains power (e.g. 110Vac) operator safety dictates that the papertape reader power pack had to be installed in an enclosure. This enclosure was incorporated into the metal stand. The metal stand was also required to mount the chad box for the tape punch. Note the metal stand is in the referenced figure for the punch in the manual.

Therefore the Teletype Model 33 ASR required the stand which was optional for the Model 33 series RO and KSR variants which were also documented in the Model 33 series manual.

An advertisement by Teletype Corporation for the [Model 33ASR](https://bitsavers.org/communications/teletype/33/273B_Mod32_33_TechMan_Jan63.pdf) displayed the base model plus options. The Base Model for $840 included the metal stand, manual reader etc.

The question asked "Could the Teletype Model 33 ASR console work on a desktop, without the dedicated stand?" The answer is no.

Edit: I had a recollection of wiring in the metal stand for the Model 33 ASR but had disposed of my maintenance manual set back in the 1970s. Just recently found a relevant Teletype Corporation advertisement for the Model 33 ASR many months too late.

Comment: You can surely position an ASR33 at the left-hand end of a desk so that the chad box hangs over the end.  Also- I think we happened to have ASR33s on our multiaccess system (no sense in not using what you have), but the reader/punch was not actually used.

Comment: But you are of course correct in that if you have an ASR33 and want to use the punch, some arrangement for chad handling is needed.  The question is therefore whether the OP really meant to ask about only the ASR model, as written, or about model 33 in general, as I and others have inferred.

Comment: Was the punch mechanism detachable?

Comment: So far I've only found Volume 1 online. The complete set includes the electrical and mechanical details. If you look at the Wikipedia page, Technical details section you can see the punch. These were mechanically driven so it did not make sense to detach them. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletype_Model_33

Comment: 'Did not work' (your opening sentence) seems a bit strong. AFAIK, only the punch wasn't readily operable, though I'm not sure whether it's a case of 'does not work' or 'makes a hellluva mess'.

Comment: @another-dave I wanted to differentiate the answer from KSR and RO versions which you could just sit on a desk or table without issue.

Really wish I had my old manual set now. In some instances there was electrical wiring in the stand but I don't remember if that was applicable to all ASR variants. If it was all variants then that would be another impediment to using a desktop.

Using the reader would also be difficult on a flat table or desk. With the stand a box holding fanfold diagnostics or programs would sit nicely under the reader and feed forward through the reader.

Comment: Belatedly had a thought... I can remember an ICL installation, so what was used in England, Australia and other Commonwealth countries with the higher penetration of the ICL 1900 series. The photos clearly show the KSR model on a desktop. See http://www.briantownsley.com/html/icl_1900.html

Comment: @PDP11 _"Of course, in theory it would always be possible to specially construct a desk installation so that it could be operated without the metal stand."_ Well, we have desks specially made for terminals (Wang 2000, Datapoint 2200, Hazeltine 2000,...) wich were, without any doubt, made to sit on top of a desk. People old enough you will remember that custom tables were the norm, not the exception - heck, they still are, just think about cable management, USB hubs tobe drilled into tables,etc. _"Throw enough money at the problem and it goes away."_ I wouldn't think the stand came for free.

Comment: The stand was always included with the base model 33 ASR.

Comment: Found the Teletype Corporations's Product Description for the Model 33 ASR which documents that stand was not optional. Updated this answer.

Answer (score 4):

> Could Teletype Model 33 ASR console work on a desktop, without the dedicated stand?

Yes, that was the most common version.

> But for some reason the fashion shifted and most hard-copy terminals in the 1960s and 1970s used a special stand.

No, not really. Some variant of the quite common '[survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias)' might be at work.

Most images we  see come from three sources:

- Marketing material of back then systems - where, of course, the system to be sold takes the center stage, not a row of TTY.
- Pictures people took of what was special - rooms full of TTY weren't.
- Or today's image from some collection/museum setup where a standalone ASR again looks way better than some additional desk and a desktop version. Not to mention that it also takes less space, which at exhibitions is a premium.

Last but not least,

- use of a TTY for/with a computer was a niche application. The majority was bought and used as what the name says: As teletypes.

So what these images are showing is everything **but** the average work situation.

Comment: I was hunting round for a picture of my university terminal room, but it seems like that was too boring to waste film on. The only photo I have is one of a friend of mine looking gleeful as he used the new 300bps (ooh!) DECwriter.

Comment: @another-dave Yes, sounds quite like the standard result when searching for average stuff. People always picture the'special'stuff, the new PDP-11, no the room with 25 TTY next door,the new IBM mainframe,not the huge room with 20 IBM data entry stations and so on. Except that was the butter and bread part of IT, what occupied the majority of people, where the real stuff was done. The shiney machines were only needed to support them.

Comment: Teletypes in large numbers were for the Telex service. Telex service used Baudot code and that was the Teletype Corporation Model 32 ASR. If you look for images of the ASR32 you will see they are nearly identical to the ASR33.  Ignore the Model 35. 

The ASR33 was the ASCII code version and would have been used exclusively with computer systems. The question was specifically about a particular model and not all the models from Teletype Corporation. For the ASR 33 it is inappropriate to state: "use of a TTY for/with a computer was a niche application." Sorry, can not accept this answer

Comment: The predecessor of the ASR 33 was the Model 15 which did sit on a desktop. With the arrival of the ASR 33 in the 1960s it was specified as a floor standing machine by DEC and others. See Wikipedia.

The ASR33 manual on Bitsavers only discusses installation onto the stand.

Comment: Per Teletype, the stand was optional. See my updated answer. The installation part of the Tech Manual says "Mounting Printer on Stand (if used)". I assume putting it on a table required no instruction :-)

Comment: @PDP11Well I very much doubt that more units have been used with computers than as TTY, regardless of code. Wiki isn't exactly authoritative when about older tech. Last bu for sure not least, why should a manual contain additional instruction for using an unmodified unit? The unmodified (und unextended) ASR33 is a desktop unit and has been used as such to my knowledge way more often than with the optional stand.

Comment: @PDP11 did other firms produce ASCII terminals?

Comment: I remembered the basically mechanical IBM selectrics could be adapted with solenoids to act as a terminal. I remember the IBM 360 had the IBM Selectrics but never knew their model number. Found on Wikipedia :  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_2741 with references to that era. For higher quality printing there were conversion kits to adapt standard IBM Selectric typewriters for home and small business use with microcomputer systems. The basically mechanical printing devices were rendered obsolete by electronics and technologies such as daisy wheel, dot matrix printers and by CRT/VDU terminals.

Comment: @Raffzahn The issue is a person asked about a specific model and people confound that with others models. Certainly there would be plenty of KSR and RO sitting on desks and tables. If that was to be their situation in an installation then those models would be purchased. People bring in the popularity of the Baudot 32 series or 33 KSR into a question about ASCII 33 ASR, etc.

If the person asking the question had generalised the question into 'could teletypes be used as a console on a desktop' then the other answers are correct. Once the person asks a specific question then specifics matter.

Comment: @another-dave Also guilty of not taking photographs of the mundane. Think the only photo I took in a terminal room was a closeup of an LSI-11.

Comment: @Anixx note that Model 33 teletypes were not necessarily ASCII devices. The ones I used had a subscript-10 character, I think with code 126 decimal.

Comment: @PDP11 definitely, IBM used desktop-based terminals at the time, but I think, they used specific interface and encoding and could not be used with minicomputers. Hence, I asked about ASR 33 which was a widely used device.

Comment: At one time I worked at a reseller of IBM Selectric conversions and these were setup for ASCII. Luckily I never had to do any of the conversions.

Comment: @Anixx IBM devices were available for various codes beside their own. For example the classic Selectric was primary meant for it's very own code which was based on the way the ball moves. But there were as well versions for other codes, including ASCII. Wang and MAI used for example ASCII versions. Same goes for TTYs being offered in many versions, not just ASCII or ITA2 but as well as manufacturer specific.

Comment: For the 33 ASR, Section 2, 2-16 Power Pack Assembly, b. "The Auxiliary ASR Power Supply is mounted in the enclosure of the stand". 2-17 Tape Punch, b. "Installation of Chad Box Assembly (Figure 2-13) , (2) "Push the box towards the rear until a bent surface located at the front of the box engages the printer stand". I had a recollection of wiring in the stand for the ASR 33 model and that is in the manual. The stand was required in the installation instructions for the tape reader  for power and the chad box for the tape puch. The stand is in the referenced figure in the manual.

Comment: Since this debate apparently can't be laid to rest, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CiUXDHtPnWY) is some video of an ASR33 **working** (as per the question asked) on a desk or bench.  I don't dispute whether a stand was always sold with the ASR33, or that punch use would be inconvenient without it. But the teletype works on a desk.

Comment: @dave Much like the one in my basement:)